# Instagram graph API IG hashtag

Tags: instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I need to get media from connected instagram profile by hashtag. For most part, I was successful, however I stumbled upon a few limitation I cannot find workaround for.

1. When I fetch media on IG user, I can send username as a field and get it back. However, I cannot get username on [IG hashtag](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/hashtag/top-media), it is not listed as field in documentation, and throws error if I send one.
2. I don't want to get back albums on IG hashtag, just image and video, but I can't seem to find a way to filter by type

What is interesting, I found an [example of site](https://www.esteelauder.com/trending-now) that displays username when filtering by hashtag, but the only way I could think of achiving this is to send request for media details for each media I receive. Needless to say, I want to avoid it.

Has anyone had a similar problem and solved it?